# Is there an idiom for querying sequences in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I'm studying to interview for a job involving a lot of SQL. I've noticed a few exercises that revolve around returning values based on a sequence across rows, and I would love to know if there's a standard way of doing this. Something akin to the subquery below I've found useful for selecting a max/min value:

```
( SELECT column FROM table ... ORDER BY column [DESC] LIMIT 1 )
```

Here's a relevant example from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/human-traffic-of-stadium/):

```
Table: Stadium

+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| id            | int     |
| visit_date    | date    |
| people        | int     |
+---------------+---------+
visit_date is the primary key for this table.
```

> Each row of this table contains the visit date and visit id to the stadium with the number of people during the visit.
> No two rows will have the same visit_date, and as the id increases, the dates increase as well.

> Write an SQL query to display the records with three or more rows with consecutive id's, and the number of people is greater than or equal to 100 for each.

> Return the result table ordered by visit_date in ascending order.

The query result format is in the following example.

```
Stadium table:
+------+------------+-----------+
| id   | visit_date | people    |
+------+------------+-----------+
| 1    | 2017-01-01 | 10        |
| 2    | 2017-01-02 | 109       |
| 3    | 2017-01-03 | 150       |
| 4    | 2017-01-04 | 99        |
| 5    | 2017-01-05 | 145       |
| 6    | 2017-01-06 | 1455      |
| 7    | 2017-01-07 | 199       |
| 8    | 2017-01-09 | 188       |
+------+------------+-----------+

Result table:
+------+------------+-----------+
| id   | visit_date | people    |
+------+------------+-----------+
| 5    | 2017-01-05 | 145       |
| 6    | 2017-01-06 | 1455      |
| 7    | 2017-01-07 | 199       |
| 8    | 2017-01-09 | 188       |
+------+------------+-----------+
```

My attempt to solve the problem used a user variable. The code below was my best shot at a solution:

```
SET @rowIndex = 0;

SELECT s1.id, s1.visit_date, s1.people
FROM ( SELECT @rowIndex:=@rowIndex+1 as rowIndex, s.id, s.visit_date, s.people
    FROM Stadium as s
    WHERE s.people >=100 ) as s1
GROUP BY rowIndex - s1.id, s1.id, s1.visit_date, s1.people
HAVING COUNT(s.id) >= 3
ORDER BY s1.visit_date
```

**The query above has a syntax error somewhere.** Message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'SELECT s1.id, s1.visit_date, s1.people FROM ( SELECT @rowIndex
> := @rowIndex+1 as' at line 4

Does anyone have a favorite way of selecting rows based on a sequence? Perhaps less importantly, can anyone spot the error in my query above?

Comment: Missing comma between `s1.id`and `s1.visit_date` in the GROUP BY.

Comment: @jarlh thanks, that's one. Edited to reflect. I ran it again and it looks like there's still an error in the query. Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would address this as a gaps-and-island problem. Here is an approach using window functions:

```
select id, visit_date, people
from (
    select s.*, count(*) over(partition by id - rn) cnt
    from (
        select s.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn
        from stadium s
        where people > 100
    ) s
) s
where cnt >= 3
```

The idea is to filter out days that have less than 100 visits, and then use the difference between  `id`  and a monotonically increasing rank to identify the islands (consecutive days with more than 100 visits). We can then retain groups that have more than 3 rows only.

Comment: Awesome looks like this does the trick. I have a question about `COUNT(*) OVER(...)` - I think I tried to achieve the same function by using COUNT() in my HAVING statement. My reasoning was that as a window function, COUNT() would return the count for the relevant window, causing the HAVING statement to weed out windows with counts less than 3. Do you think this is correct?